# Objects get stuck on hitting an invisible version of other recently removed objects

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hello Everyone I'm having trouble with a simple flash game. So far it is trouble removing projectiles once they have hit an object.

After going through the site found out to add .parent.removeChild(wtv); to remove the objects.  When used the object that is fired by my player hits an object, both are removed but when another is fired at the same position the fired object hits an invisible object that was just removed and is then removed at that position instead of carrying on until the end of the stage or another object is hit.  This seems to only happen when the fired object is removed.

This is the code, the problem i believe is in the moveLaser Function, if anymore information is needed please let me know, any recommendations would be great, thank you.

```
package{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.display3D.IndexBuffer3D;


public class Level_1 extends MovieClip{
    private var player:SpaceShip;
    private var objects:Array;
    private var probMoveObj:int;
    private var bgStars:Level1_stars;

    public function Level_1(){
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
    }

    public function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void{
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);

        probMoveObj = 1;

        bgStars = new Level1_stars();
        player = new SpaceShip();
        objects = new Array(50);

        bgStars.vx = 50;
        addChild(bgStars);

        for(var i:int = 0; i < objects.length; i++){
            objects[i] = new GameObject();
            addGameObjects(objects[i]);
        }

        player.x = 100;
        player.y = stage.stageHeight - 250;
        addChild(player);

        bgStars.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBackground);
        player.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movePlayer);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, checkKey);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, checkFire);

    }

    public function movePlayer(event:Event):void{

        /*for(var i:int = 0; i < objects.length; i++){
            if(objects[i].hitTestObject(player.hit)){
                objects[i].removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveObject);
                trace("HIT");
            }
        }*/
    }

    public function checkFire(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){
            trace("SPACE");
            var laser:Ship_laser = new Ship_laser();
            var laser2:Ship_laser = new Ship_laser();
            laser.x  = player.x + 30;
            laser2.x = player.x + 30;
            laser.y = player.y - 30;
            laser2.y = player.y + 30;
            laser.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveLaser);
            laser2.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveLaser);
            addChild(laser);
            addChild(laser2);
        }
    }

    public function checkKey(event:KeyboardEvent):void{

        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
            if((player.y - (player.height / 2)) >= 0){
                player.y -= 10;
                trace("UP");
            }
        }
        else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
            if((player.y +(player.height / 2)) <= stage.stageHeight){
                player.y += 10;
                trace("down");
            }
        }
        else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
            if(player.x - (player.width / 2) >= 0){
                player.x -= 10;
                trace("LEFT");
            }
        }
        else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
            if(player.x + (player.width / 2) <= stage.stageWidth){
                player.x += 10;
                trace("RIGHT");
            }
        }
    }

    public function addGameObjects(gameObj:GameObject):void{
        // position the object randomly, but to the right of the player
            gameObj.x = stage.stageWidth + (Math.ceil(Math.random() * (4000 + gameObj.width/2)));
            gameObj.y = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (stage.stageHeight - 100 - gameObj.height/2));
            // add object to the stage
            addChild(gameObj);
            // set the velocity of the object
            gameObj.vx = -Math.ceil((Math.random() + 1) * 2);
            // move the object each frame
            gameObj.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveObject);
    }

    private function moveObject(event:Event):void
    {
        var gameObj:GameObject = event.target as GameObject;
        gameObj.x += gameObj.vx;
    }

    private function moveBackground(event:Event):void{

        if(bgStars.x < ((bgStars.width / 2 + 100) * -1)){
            bgStars.x = 0;   
        }
        else{
            bgStars.x -= bgStars.vx;
        }
    }

    private function moveLaser(event:Event):void{

        var laser:Ship_laser = event.target as Ship_laser;

        for(var i:int = 0; i < objects.length; i++){
            if(objects[i].hitTestObject(laser.hit)){
                objects[i].removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveObject);
                if(objects[i].parent){
                    objects[i].parent.removeChild(objects[i]);
                }

                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveLaser);
                if(laser.parent){
                    laser.parent.removeChild(laser);
                }

            }
        }

        if(laser.x > stage.stageWidth){
            trace("LASER REMOVED");

            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveLaser);
            if(laser.parent){
                laser.parent.removeChild(laser);
            }
        }
        else{
            laser.x += 20;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Your `laser` object is attached to `this`, but you for some weirdest reason call `laser.removeChild()` essentially asking that `laser` will remove itself from itself. You have omitted `parent` there.

```
laser.parent.removeChild(laser);
```

Also, there is a flaw if your laser will both reach edge of the stage and hit a `gameObject` on the same frame, you'll hit a 1009 error for attempting to remove `laser` twice in a row, first call nulls `laser.parent` and second call will call a method of null reference. You have to fix this issue too, probably via `if (laser.parent)` as you did with objects.

Update: You also remove the event listener from wrong object, you are attaching it to a laser, and removing from `this` which is not a laser. You should do:

```
laser.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveLaser);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! and sorry thanks for noticing that! that was supposed to be removed before the post.  The problem I now face after adding laser.parent, is that the laser is removed but when another hits that position where the last was removed, it is like it is hitting an invisible object and being removed at that position instead of carrying on until it hits a different object or goes out of bounds.  Any ideas on why this might be happening?